# What CloudFront/S3 doing with HTML/CSS/JS files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I uploaded to S3 below files:

- EntryPoint__fd6b122d5ca60cd57ec5.js
- index.html
- Main.css

But server returns below content:

[image]

Especially the gray one is strange: it does not seems like file.
It's name (filename?) is ID from URN:

```
https://XXXX.com/product/53483ca1-9fd1-4970-841d-e9fbeadd4660
```

[image]

But when I checked the content of `EntryPoint__fd6b122d5ca60cd57ec5.js`, `Main.css`, I saw the same HTML code as in picture above (by other words, content of `53483ca1-9fd1-4970-841d-e9fbeadd4660`, `Main.css` and `EntryPoint__fd6b122d5ca60cd57ec5.js` is even).

I have error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'    
EntryPoint__fd6b122d5ca60cd57ec5.js:1
```

To solve this error, first I need to understand what CloudFront/S3 did with my files. What is gray one? Where it's name has been set?

Anyway, it did something wrong: `EntryPoint__fd6b122d5ca60cd57ec5.js` has HTML content, and certainly
JavaScript can not parse it.

### Update or request: deploying to S3 task

```
const applicationDeployment = ({
  targetFilesGlobSelections,
  targetIsFunctionalTesting = false
}) =>

   Gulp.src(targetFilesGlobSelections)

       .pipe(GulpPlugins.plumber({
         errorHandler: (error) => {
           console.error("Task: 'DeployApplication', error occurred:");
           console.error(error);
           NodeNotifier.notify({
             title: "Task: 'DeployApplication', error occurred:",
             message: error.message
           });
         }
       }))

       .pipe(GulpPlugins.s3(
          targetIsFunctionalTesting ? AMAZON_S3_DEPLOYMENT_CONFIG__FUNCTIONAL_STAGING : AMAZON_S3_DEPLOYMENT_CONFIG__PRODUCTION
       ));

Gulp.task("Deployment to production", () => applicationDeployment({
  targetFilesGlobSelections: `${public}/**/**`
}));
```

Comment: are you getting this error when you run it locally?

Comment: @sagar1025, No.

Comment: is it possible to share the contents of the js file that's being loaded?

Comment: @sagar1025 afraid no, because it's real commercial project. I can just say that it is minified .js file has been built by Webpack and a huge part of it is libraries.

Comment: How did you upload the files?

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver, With [gulp-s3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-s3).

Comment: Could you please include the code that's doing the file upload?

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver, O'K, I added it. But please note that I has not found any malfunction with files uploading before: submitted files is completely even with files in server storage. Also, this problem will no occur of to use hash mode in frontend routing (e. g. https://XXXX.com/**#**/product/53483ca1-9fd1-4970-841d-e9fbeadd4660). So, the probability of the cause is uploading sequence is low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

1. The viewer requests the website at [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).
2. If the requested object is cached, CloudFront returns the object from
   its cache to the viewer.
3. If the object is not in CloudFront’s cache, CloudFront requests the
   object from the origin (an S3 bucket).
4. S3 returns the object to CloudFront, which triggers the Lambda@Edge
   origin response event.
5. **The object, including the security headers added by the Lambda@Edge
   function, is added to CloudFront’s cache.**
6. (Not shown) The objects is returned to the viewer. Subsequent
   requests for the object that come to the same CloudFront edge
   location are served from the CloudFront cache.

**As mentioned in 5th point, let elaborate the Lambda@Edge more! There are many uses for Lambda@Edge processing. For example:**

- **A Lambda function can inspect cookies and rewrite URLs so that users
  see different versions of a site for A/B testing.**
- CloudFront can return different objects to viewers based on the
  device they're using by checking the User-Agent header, which
  includes information about the devices. For example, CloudFront can
  return different images based on the screen size of their device.
  Similarly, the function could consider the value of the Referer
  header and cause CloudFront to return the images to bots that have
  the lowest available resolution.
- Or you could check cookies for other criteria. For example, on a
  retail website that sells clothing, if you use cookies to indicate
  which color a user chose for a jacket, a Lambda function can change
  the request so that CloudFront returns the image of a jacket in the
  selected color.
- A Lambda function can generate HTTP responses when CloudFront viewer
  request or origin request events occur.
- A function can inspect headers or authorization tokens, and insert a
  header to control access to your content before CloudFront forwards
  the request to your origin.
- A Lambda function can also make network calls to external resources
  to confirm user credentials, or fetch additional content to customize
  a response.

I hope it can help you to understand what happened to your files. By the in inspect grey files mean HTML, orange/yellow mean javascript or .js file and blue mean css file.

Following is the example of my files!

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll try to solve this problem again this week and report about results.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! You suggested the working solution alternative.